# File Watcher, and File.copy program confusion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file-copying, file-watcher

Hello Stack Overflow community, I'm still learning the basics of c# and am need of some guidance. I've read a lot of material on the Microsoft site, and Stack Overflow too, but not finding a solution. My issue is that I'm trying to setup my File Watcher program so that when new files are added, they are not over written in the destination directory but added. It seems I can only get one file to create in the destination directory, and any other new files created are over written. 
My other challenge is to reflect the file that is being created in the destination directory. For instance, if I create a blank .bmp file, the destination directory will add a "whatever.txt" file by default. I've pasted my code below, and welcome any thoughts. Thanks kindly SO community.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;


namespace Generac_fileWatcher
{


public class FileWatcher
{
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        //string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        //// If a directory is not specified, exit program.
        //if (args.Length != 2)
        //{
        //    // Display the proper way to call the program.
        //    Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
        //    return;
        //}

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        //watcher.Path = args[1];
        watcher.Path = @"C:\Users\mterpeza\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Generac_fileWatcher\Generac_fileWatcher\FilesToWatch";
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = ""; 

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        File.Copy(e.FullPath, @"C:\Users\mterpeza\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Generac_fileWatcher\Generac_fileWatcher\SyncedDirectory\whatever.txt", true);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hardcoding the filename of the copied file.

```
File.Copy(e.FullPath, @"C:\Users\mterpeza\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Generac_fileWatcher\Generac_fileWatcher\SyncedDirectory\whatever.txt", true);
```

All files will be copied as 'whatever.txt' in the SyncedDirectory, which means that all files after the first will be overwritten, since there can only be one file with a given name in a directory. If you would like the copied file to use its own name, you should do something like the following instead.

```
//note that targetDirectory does NOT contain 'whatever.txt'
var targetDirectory = @"C:\Users\mterpeza\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Generac_fileWatcher\Generac_fileWatcher\SyncedDirectory\";
var targetPath = Path.Combine(targetDirectory, e.Name);
File.Copy(e.FullPath, targetPath, true);
```

This way, each file will keep its name when it gets copied, but will still go to the directory you specify.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I appreciate the help and guidance! My only issue I'm facing now is, when I test the code you suggested I get a red squiggle line under e.FullName. I'll continue further testing, but any idea why this might be happening? Again, thanks!

Comment: @MikeTerpeza That was my bad, it should have been FullPath not FullName. It is fixed now.

Comment: No worries @BrandonKramer, very grateful for your help!

Comment: Always glad to help out!